# SharePoint 2013 REST API Filter hidden Fields

Tags: 2013, filter, sharepoint-rest-api, role-assignment

I have a little Problem. I'm trying to do the following. There is a Field on SharePoint List items called HasUniqueRoleAssignments that is hidden on a standard REST call. If I put it in the select string of the rest call I will retrieve it. So far so good.
But what I apperently can't do is use it in the filter statement. So the URL

```
.../sites/site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Listname')/items?$filter=(Some_Standard_Field%20eq%20%27139%27)&$select=Id,HasUniqueRoleAssignments,Author/Title,Editor/Title,Created,Some_Standard_FieldId&$expand=Author,Editor&$top=1000
```

will work just fine. But if I try

```
.../sites/site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Listname')/items?$filter=(HasUniqueRoleAssignments%20eq%20%27false%27)&$select=Id,HasUniqueRoleAssignments&$top=1000
```

the request will fail with the error message, that the column HasUniqueRoleAssignments is not available.

Does anyone have an idea, how to use the filter to get items with

```
HasUniqueRoleAssignments = false or true?
```

Would be thankful for help

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this endpoint:

```
.../sites/site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Listname')/items?$select=Id,HasUniqueRoleAssignments&$filter=HasUniqueRoleAssignments eq 0&$top=1000
```

?

Filtering a boolean field with 'false' means a string.

If you want filter true use: 
`eq 1` instead of `eq 'false'`.

And false use: `eq 0` instead of `eq 'true'`.

Comment: sadly that doesn't work. The problem doesn't seem to be the value I'm filtering but the Column. SharePoint tells me that it doesn't exist even though it obviously does

Comment: Hasuniqueroleassignment is a property, not a column. You cannot use $filter with properties as a condition.  $filter will only work with columns.

Answer (score 0):

Its a hidden property can't be used in rest filtering, what you can do is copy the value of it in a metadata on item creation / edit (depends on your instances) and use that created metadata to filter your items.

Hope it helps! Happy SharePointing!

Answer (score 0):

Better to just get all of the items, and include the `HasUniqueRoleAssignments` in your `$select` statement, then do the filtering in your AJAX call's success function afterwards:

```
success: function (data) {
    var items = data.d.results;
    if (items.length > 0) {
        for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (items[i].HasUniqueRoleAssignments == "true") {
                // do some stuff....
            }
        }
    }
},
```

I know it's not ideal, but it will get the job done. You can't filter on properties, only column values.